# Use recurrence relations to find strings with odd numbers of 0's

Tags: recurrence-relations

You are given all n-digit strings in which each digit is 0, 1, or 2.
Using the product rule and/or the sum rule, count the number of these
strings that have an odd number of 0’s when n (the number of digits in
the string) is equal to

(a) 1

I got $1$ string, which is $0$

(b) 2

$2\times1 = 2$ and $1 \times 2 = 2.$

Then $2+2=4$ strings.

(c) 3

We can have 1 or 3 $0$'s.

For 1:
$1\times2\times2=4$ and $2\times1\times2=4$ and $2\times2\times1=4$

For 3:
$1\times1\times1=1$

Then, $4+4+4+1=13$ strings.

(d) 4.

We can have 1 or 3 $0$'s.

For 1:
$1\times2\times2\times2=8$ and $2\times1\times2\times2=8$ and$2\times2\times1\times2=8$ and $2\times2\times2\times1=8$

For 3:
$1\times1\times1\times2=2$ and $1\times1\times2\times1=2$ and $1\times2\times1\times1=2$ and $2\times1\times1\times1=2$

Then, $8+8+8+8+2+2+2+2=40$ strings.

Using recurrence relations, count the number of these strings that have
an odd number of 0’s in all n-digit strings.
Once you get the (closed-form) formula, verify that your answers to (a)
through (d) are correct.

Comment: What have you tried?  For the first three there are few enough to write them all down.  That might give some inspiration.  What do you know about recurrence relations?  You are trying to find the number of strings of length $n$ based on the number of length $n-1$ and maybe $n-2$

Comment: I got the title wrong. Corrected.

Comment: Your hand count is correct for the first four.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Let $E(n)$ be the number of strings with an even number of zeros and $O(n)$ be the number with an odd number of zeros.  Can you write an equation for $E(n)$ in terms of $E(n-1), O(n-1)$ and similarly for $O(n)?$  If you have string of length $n-1$ with an even number of zeros and extend it by one digit...

Added: a string of $n$ digits with an odd number of $0$'s can come from a string of length $n-1$ with an odd number of $0$'s that we add a $1$ or a $2$ to, or from a string of length $n-1$ with an even number of $0$'s that we add a $0$ to.  The recurrence is then $O(n)=2O(n-1)+E(n-1)$.  Similarly we have $E(n)=2E(n-1)+O(n-1)$.  The base condition is $O(0)=0,E(0)=1$ because the empty string has an even number of $0$'s.

We know $E(n)+O(n)=3^n$ because every string of length $n$ has either an even or odd number of $0$'s.  We then have $$O(n)=2O(n-1)+3^{n-1}-O(n-1)\\O(n)=3^{n-1}+O(n-1)$$ and we can sum the geometric series to get $$O(n)=\frac 12(3^n-1)\\E(n)=\frac 12(3^n+1)$$

Comment: I've gotten a sequence ${1,4,13,40,...}$. So, $O(0) = 1$ is the initial condition, and $O(n) = 3(O(n-1))+1$ is the recurrent condition. Am I getting there?

Comment: No, $O(0)=0$ because the empty string does not have an odd number of zeros.  $E(0)=1$.  Then an odd string of length $n$ is either an odd string of length $n-1$ with a $1$ or $2$ added or an even string of length $n-1$ with a $0$ added.  I agree with your $1,4,13,40\ldots$.  Your recurrence produces the right answers but I don't see how it is justified.

Comment: Hmm. Then the sequence is actually $0,1,4,13,40,....$ , right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It is $\frac 12(3^n-1)$

Comment: Ok, then $O(0) = 0$ is the initial condition. $O(n)=3(O(n-1))+1$ , $n \geq 1$ is the recurrent. I feel like I'm still way off.

Comment: Just saw that^. Disregard.