# How many n-letter words are there, such that number of letters "a" is even?

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, combinatorics-on-words

> How many n-letter words (made of letters from 25-letter english alphabet) are there, such that number of letters "a" is even? ("a" appears even number of times in a word).

I'm trying to create recursive formula, but with no success.

Comment: If we have a "good" word of length $n-1$, how many letters can we append to make a good word of length $n$?  Same question if we have a "bad" word of length $n-1$.

Comment: What happened to the missing letter?

Comment: The same question, with two other letters instead of 24, is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948773/use-recurrence-relations-to-find-strings-with-odd-numbers-of-0s/2948910#2948910)

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $o_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words with an odd number of $a$'s and

let $e_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words with an even number of $a$'s.

Then $o_n+e_n = 25^n$ and $$ e_{n+1} = o_n+ 24e_n$$

that is, if the first letter is $a$ then in the rest of a word must be an odd number of $a$'s and if the first letter is not $a$ then the number of even $a$'s is the same as in an $n$-letter word times 24 (since we have 24 choices for the first number) .